# 2006 Saturn Vue 4cyl

Tags: electrical, starting, troubleshooting

Starter spinningfreely not engaging the flywheel to crank the engine I've changed the starter and the new starter does the same thing it's not engaging the engine it's just spinning freely so what would cause this to happen of check crank position sensors I've checked ignition relays change the starter and it's all doing the same thing would it be a battery issue or is there something else I need to diagnos

Comment: Sounds like a timing belt or chain has broken.

Comment: @Moab - They state the engine isn't turning ... just the starter motor.

Comment: Fractured teeth on the engine's flywheel ring gear would cause this.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 maybe that's an assumption.

Comment: @Moab - Could be.